# Is there an inbuilt microphone on the Toshiba Dynabook Satellite J50?

Tags: microphone, toshiba-laptop, hardware-detection

Is there an inbuilt microphone on the Toshiba Dynabook Satellite J50?

If so, where is it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from these images of the laptop ([img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF6zF.jpg), [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOkpC.jpg), [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvIPi.jpg), [img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7fia.jpg)), I can say there is **no** built-in microphone on it. So you have to use an external microphone.